# LastPass authentication grid hacked on June 15?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, lastpass

I wonder how safe LastPass's grid authentication is. I take it that they have a copy of the authentication grid on their server. You are supposed to print the grid and carry it with you to any device that you're accessing LastPass from. If this grid was stolen (as plain text), what is its use?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking what the grid is for? How does the breach on June 15 affect the question?

Answer (score 4):

As with any two-factor authentication (2FA) method, then you're back to essentially only having a password protecting your account. But with grids I'd consider the printout a greater security risk than the server getting hacked.

The thing that I find hilarious about grids as a 2FA method is that A) they are too complex to memorize, so you HAVE to have a physical copy, and B) they are super easy to take a photo of.

Some companies print 2FA grids on the back of employee badges, which means that I can turn on my phone camera, walk through the building and capture 50% of employees' grids. Dumb.

Comment: It depends on what your threat actor you want to protect yourself from. If I can't use a phone, I'd prefer a printout than to do nothing at all for a 2nd factor.

Comment: @schroeder as long as your organization doesn't decide that having 2FA means they can permit weak passwords. I've been getting whiffs of that argument, that 2FA means you can use super-simple common passwords everywhere. Sorry, no.  ;-)

Comment: @Craig saying "no" is far too simple a response. Passwords (and their complexity) and 2FA exist to address risks from threat actors. It is perfectly reasonable to allow simple passwords when you have 2FA, depending on the risks involved. In some cases, you're correct, the risk is still too high, but you need to understand the elements of the risk and the threat actors.

Comment: @schroeder I respectfully disagree. I'm not opposed to models and identifying threat actors. But I'd also assert that the users themselves are threat actors in the sense that they tend to use really lame credentials and practice really weak security awareness. Allow that in one area, it bleeds over into others. There's also a LOT of hype around 2FA right now. It helps, but how easy is it for a threat actor to clone a cell phone? (easy) How easy is it for somebody to steal a cell phone, maybe only for 30 seconds to effect a login? (easy)

Comment: I'm curious how many banks have enabled weak passwords with 2FA for their employees with access to highly sensitive data? It's well known that they use a different standard for their employees (where security is a job requirement and highly critical) vs their customers (where a threat mitigation assessment tells them how quickly they can detect and respond to compromised customer web banking accounts, so they can assess that cost vs the cost of imposing better security requirements on their customers).

Comment: @Craig I'm not sure what you disagree with. I agree with all your statements, but your comments highlight the need for understanding context. All of your proposed attack vectors require physical access to the 2nd factor. If someone steals your phone, then all bets are off, no matter how strong your password is. Using a phone as a second factor mitigates the threat of a remote treat actor.

Comment: @schroeder Just with promoting the idea that 2FA makes strong passwords irrelevant. It *does* matter how strong your password is if your mobile gets stolen. I've been hearing from people who don't really understand the implications that we must enable 2FA *because* that will let us enable short, weak passwords, because somebody read an article during a flight about what CitiBank is doing for customer-facing online banking logons and naively assumed it applies to all types of logons. Point being why promote weak security in *any* context?

Comment: The "we must enable short, pointless passwords by enabling 2FA" argument also misses the important point (among *many*) that the 2FA must be implemented for every subsystem that utilizes your directory security or it's borderline pointless (every Windows, Linux and Intranet/web logon, etc.) And that isn't likely to happen quickly, or in some cases at all. It's just so easy for people to presume that there is such a thing as a silver bullet when, in fact, there is not, and then that half-knowledge ends up being used to officially dictate weak solutions in the wrong context.

Comment: @Craig you are conflating too many ideas and missing the point.

Comment: @schroeder 9,000 major security breaches last year...  I think *maybe* too few people conflated enough ideas to get the full picture, missed the point, and everybody is paying for it.  ;-)